# How to close dialog from out side dialog code?

Tags: android

I have material Dialog and I want to close is like this?

```
 val smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault() as SmsManager
        dialogSendSmsBinding.edtLytSendSms.setEndIconOnClickListener {
            val message = dialogSendSmsBinding.edtSendSms.text.toString().trim()
            if (message.isEmpty()) {
                ValidatorUtils.validateInput(ctx, dialogSendSmsBinding.edtSendSms)
            } else {
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phone, null, message, null, null)
                MessageUtils.showToastMessage(ctx, ctx.getString(R.string.str_sms_sending))
                // I want to dismiss Dialog here how to do it?
            }
        }
        messageDialogBuilder.setView(dialogSendSmsBinding.root)
                .setTitle(ctx.getString(R.string.str_sms_dialog))
                .setMessage(ctx.getString(R.string.str_sms_dialog_hint))
                .setNegativeButton(ctx.getString(R.string.str_cancel)) { dialog, _ ->
                    dialog.dismiss()
                }
                .show()
```

please help me out to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `create` method in `DialogBuilder` to get the created dialog and hold the reference of it in global variable

```
val dialog: AlertDialog? = null

 val smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault() as SmsManager
        dialogSendSmsBinding.edtLytSendSms.setEndIconOnClickListener {
            val message = dialogSendSmsBinding.edtSendSms.text.toString().trim()
            if (message.isEmpty()) {
                ValidatorUtils.validateInput(ctx, dialogSendSmsBinding.edtSendSms)
            } else {
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phone, null, message, null, null)
                MessageUtils.showToastMessage(ctx, ctx.getString(R.string.str_sms_sending))
                 dialog?.dismis()
            }
        }
        messageDialogBuilder.setView(dialogSendSmsBinding.root)
                .setTitle(ctx.getString(R.string.str_sms_dialog))
                .setMessage(ctx.getString(R.string.str_sms_dialog_hint))
                .setNegativeButton(ctx.getString(R.string.str_cancel)) { dialog, _ ->
                    dialog.dismiss()
                }
        dialog = messageDialogBuilder.create()
        dialog.show()
```